# Permanently change field size in Joomla database

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to increase the size of a field in the joomla database (table jos_menu, field link). Any idea what will happen to it when a new version of Joomla comes out and I do a Joomla upgrade? Will the  field gets resized on upgrade, hence losing some of my stored data? How do I prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

(Joomla 2.5.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables should be fine with minor updates however you never know if Joomla will require changes to the `#__menu` table in the future. Lots of changes were made to the database structure in Joomla 1.6 so what's to say it won't happen in Joomla 4.0 (when released). I would say you should be ok when changing the size of the field but every time you update Joomla, just double check that none of the changes have been reverted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However if I left it so that I checked whether the changes have been reverted, I would already have lost some of my data. I appreciate I would have backed-up the database before upgrading so can restore the data, but wondered if I could prevent it in the first place?

Comment: Do you know whether, within a family of releases (eg Joomla 2.x, Joomla 3.x etc), that the database structure doesn't change, but only does between major releases eg 2->3, 3->4 etc? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way you can prevent it being reverted upon an update unless you use your own custom database table which extends the current `#__menu` one. This would be the best approach. I have looked at the J2.5 and J3.3 menu database tables and the only difference I saw was the `ordering` column had been removed. Never the less, this is still a change and therefore there might be another change in 4.x, therefore you should do what I suggested with using your own custom database table and possible develop a small plugin to go with it